# How can I create a frame which includes animation?

Tags: java, animation

I have a frame and I want to show some white sphere in the different location in my frame,I have researched a lot but I found some codes for using applets but i don't want to use applets.
please help me with some code or references.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sun has published a [large list of Java 2D examples](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/samples/suite/), many of which include animation. You should be able to copy the techniques used there. Take a look!

---

Note: "Java 2D" sounds like some API that you'd need to download a new library for. This is not the case: Java 2D is part of the "normal" JDK/JRE libraries.

---

Another note: There's not too much difference between an Applet showing graphics and a desktop application. To convert a Swing Applet to a desktop application, most of the effort is replacing `JApplet` with `JFrame`, and moving the applet's `init` code into the JFrame's constructor. So if you see example code for applets, don't throw it out the window as it can still be useful to you.

Comment: Carl's right about applets. This simple animation example runs as either an application or an applet: http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway

Answer (score -1):

You may also like this [*Java 2D games tutorial*](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/) that discusses several animation techniques.